# Having an issue with selecting and displaying distinct values in a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am attempting to represent the size of an item. We have multiple suppliers and the table we use to store the values of sizes and suppliers means that we have several sizes that equal the same value, but different supplier.

I need to populate the following drop down list, but can't have duplicates of say for example S, M or L:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.RejectLog.SupplierTypeId, 
    new SelectList(Model.SupplierTypes, "ID", "Size", 
                   Model.RejectLog.SupplierTypeId), 
    new { 
        @size = Model.SupplierTypes.Count,
        @class = "reject-select",
        @id = "Size",
        @name = "Size"
    }
)
```

I have tried adding `.Distinct()` nearly every place I could. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I removed some of your tags (e.g. *html*) because they were not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your code as follows:

```
new SelectList(
    Model.SupplierTypes.Select( t => new {ID = t.ID, Size = t.Size} )
                       .Distinct(), 
    "ID", "Size", Model.RejectLog.SupplierTypeId)
```

---

If you want select only a size (and have the size value itself, not the associated ID, returned to the server) then you can just use Size as the Display value and as the "Identity" value:

```
new SelectList(
    Model.SupplierTypes.Select( t => new {Size = t.Size} )
                       .Distinct(), 
    "Size", "Size", ???)
```

*(I am very, very new to Razor, so I'm not sure what is expected in that fourth parameter. As you are no longer using the ID, however, I would think that it must be reexamined.)*

Comment: Everything in there looks like it should work. Tried it out and received the same results. Did an iisreset and cleared the cache and still no go. Will keep digging.

Comment: The `.Distinct()` function will find all of the distinct values of both ID and Size. If you have elements `{ID=1, Size="S"}` and `{ID=2, Size="S"}`, then `.Distinct()` will return both (since the ID is different).

Comment: Ok. I'm terribly sorry and I should've included it in the original question but I need distinct values for "Size." Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkSaluta - So, what happens if there's more than one ID for Size? Which ID should you use?

Comment: In the current data structure, there is no scenario where there would be more than one ID for Size. The ID is just an ascending integer. What I'm needing to do is to select only the distinct Size...

Comment: @MarkSaluta - I'm confused... why are there multiple values of Size? If there is only ever one ID associated with one Size, then there should never be multiple values of Size (as you have indicated, Size is an ascending int, presumably auto-generated). You shouldn't have to call Distinct in the first place.

Comment: I apologize if I'm confusing people. So we've got three columns: ID, SupplierTypeId and Size. Take for example the first three: (1; brand X; Small)(2; brand Y; Small)(3; brand X; Medium). So what I'm trying to get from those three columns would be a dropdown list with just one Small and one Medium. What I'm getting is Small, Small, Medium.

Comment: A select list has two "values" for each item: the displayed value and what I will call the identity value. The displayed value is what the user can see in the list. The identity value is what is returned to the server when the user selects an item. Currently, your select list is using the "ID" as the identity value, meaning "Small" can have an identity value of 1 or 2. Is that what you mean to do? If so, which ID do you want to use?

Comment: After speaking with the BA, we currently do not use the ID for anything. So we would not need to use that as a filter. So perhaps a SelectList is not the approach we should be making. Would there be a more prudent approach for displaying distinct Sizes?

Comment: Makes sense, just not sure what the fourth parameter would be.

Comment: Did away with SupplierTypeId and the duplicates. The business process has a different way of accounting for the supplier type external to this table.